# Backup folder with a specific file inside with rsync

Tags: linux, unix, rsync

I'm using backupPC for backing up some .xml files in a Linux machine.

Specifically, we just need files called "config.xml"

For achieving it, I'm using backupPC with rsync, with these include/exclude parameters

```
--include="*/ --include="config.xml" --exclude="*"
```

in this way, i'm having lots of empty folders, and some with config.xml inside.

Is there a way to exclude all the folders which don't have config.xml inside?

Comment: It's off-topic here. Try asking on http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0):

The option you are looking for is `--prune-empty-dirs`.